# Error on JsonPatch Add on Array

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api2, json-patch

I'm using KevinDockx-Jsonpatch library (v2.1.0 - [GitHub](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch)) in a .NET Web API project to receive jsonpatch partial updates from a Web API.

I'm trying to add an element to an array with a patch like this:

```
[{
"op": "add",
"path": "/links/8",
"value": {
    "linkName": "test",
    "linkValue": "http://test.com",
    "id": 0,
    "websiteId": 123,
    "valid": true
}}]
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error: `TargetLocationAtPathSegmentNotFound`

It seems that the lib is checking not for the array position but for a path called links/4 and obviously it is not able to find it. 
I've also tried with links/- but there is the same problem.

My model on server is written using Entity Framework Code First approach.

So I have an object like this:

```
[Table("XXX.Websites")]
public partial class Website : Entity
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Try removing the "/8" from the path and changing the "id" value to "8".

Comment: Hello @ParanoidCoder and thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work and it's conceptually different from my intent. The "id" field it's DB id field, so setting it to 0 form Entity Framework should means "Create new record in table Likns".
In my intent, with this add I'd like to:
1) create new record in table Links (I added foreign key in the post "websiteId")
2) append this relationship to my Website object.
2) add a